# HTTP2 Request cannot be send via JMeter

Tags: jmeter, http2

I'm trying to send HTTP2 requests via JMeter. 
[image: I use the following request configuration:]

I've downloaded alpn-boot file according to my java version: java version "1.8.0_151" -> ALPN version is 8.1.11.v20170118 (according to https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/alpn-chapter.html#alpn-versions). Also, I've added the path to alpn-boot file to jmeter.bat:

```
set JVM_ARGS= -Xbootclasspath/p:D:\apache-jmeter-5.1\apache-jmeter-5.1\lib\alpn-boot-8.1.11.v20170118.jar
@echo off

rem   Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
rem   contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
...
```

But I get an error message in JMeter:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:138)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Connection.connect(HTTP2Connection.java:69)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.setConnection(HTTP2Request.java:280)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:140)
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.http2.sampler.HTTP2Request.sample(HTTP2Request.java:117)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:475)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:418)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:249)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client ALPNProcessors!
    at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client.lambda$doStart$1(HTTP2Client.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http2.client.HTTP2Client$ClientSelectorManager.newConnection(HTTP2Client.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.createEndPoint(ManagedSelector.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.access$1500(ManagedSelector.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector$CreateEndPoint.run(ManagedSelector.java:825)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/alpn/ALPN
        at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.java.client.OpenJDK8ClientALPNProcessor.init(OpenJDK8ClientALPNProcessor.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.client.ALPNClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ALPNClientConnectionFactory.java:77)
        ... 8 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.jetty.alpn.ALPN
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 10 more
```

I guess the issue is connected with alpn path in jmeter.bat file, but how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all ensure that JMeter is using your Java 1.8.0_151 and taking the `-Xbootclasspath` argument, you can do this by adding a [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and using the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code:

   ```
    log.info('Java version: ' + System.getProperty('java.version'))
    java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getInputArguments().each {
        log.info("Effective JVM argument: " + "$it")
    }
   ```

   you should get the output like:

   [image]
2. Check that the `alpn-boot` file is **really** there:

   [image]
3. Sanitize the input, i.e. remove whitespace, add a semicolon at the end and surround the value with quotation marks:

   ```
   set JVM_ARGS="-Xbootclasspath/p:D:\apache-jmeter-5.1\apache-jmeter-5.1\lib\alpn-boot-8.1.11.v20170118.jar;"
   ```
4. If everything goes well you should be able to successfully execute the HTTP2 request:

   [image]

More information: [The New HTTP/2 Plugin for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-http2-plugin-for-jmeter-the-complete-guide/)

Comment: Thank You for the reply. I've followed the steps you've provided and the result is the following:
JMeter Java version matches the version I've got using the console. But JMeter does not take the -Xbootclasspath argument unless the alpn-boot file is really there

Comment: HTTP2 request still cannot be sent